# test or prevent some relative path imports / requires

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, require

I have a folder structure like so:

```
.
└── client                   
    ├── components           
    └── routes               
        ├── index.js         
        ├── Login            
        │   ├── index.js     
        │   ├── assets       
        │   ├── components   
        │   ├── container    
        │   └── modules
        └── UpdatePassword
            ├── index.js     
            ├── assets       
            ├── components   
            ├── container    
            └── modules
```

I would like to see if anyone is importing files from the `UpdatePassword` folder to the `Login` folder and vice versa.

Basically I'm following a fractal project structure where I want components that are related to the `UpdatePassword` or `Login` route to only exist in their respective folders. Shared components would exist in the `client/components` subdirectory. To maintain a structure like this, I would like to write a test that fails when an 'unacceptable' `imports` or `require` is used. I.e. if a file in `UpdatePassword` `imports` from `Login/components`.

Is there a way to test or check whether an import is coming from specific folders?

Answer (score 0):

Try **[madge](https://github.com/pahen/madge)**: I usually run it as `madge --image /path-to-folder/dependencies.png routes` (There is also a `exclude` option if you need it)

You'll get a visual graph which shows you dependencies between files.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea about native way to do it.But you can wrap "require" function:

```
function myRequire(fromPath, requiredPath) {
  //code to judge whether or not can load requiredPath from fromPath
  var can = ...

  if(can) {
    return require(requiredPath);
  }
  else {
    throw new Error(`you can not load ${requiredPath} from ${fromPath}`);
  }
}
```